# php calculator function variable and time

Tags: php

Hi I am trying to create a php calculator which basically does this:

```
$price_m_Fuengirola = 11.00;

/* number of people */

$car1 = 0.00; /* 1-4 */
$car2 = 50.00; /* 4-8 */
$car3 = 70.00; /* 8-12 */
$car4 = 90.00; /* 12-16 */

/* Calculator */

date_default_timezone_set('GMT');

//echo $newTime;

echo $price_m_Fuengirola."<br />";

echo $car2."<br />";

function timeCalc(){
$newTime = date("H:i", time());

if ($newTime < "18:56"){

    echo 20.00;
    //echo "<br />this is more time";

} else {

    echo 6.00;
    //echo "this is more time";

}
}


$timeCalc = timeCalc();

echo $timeCalc."<br />";

$total = $price_m_Fuengirola + $car2 + $timeCalc."<br /><br />";

echo $total;`
```

The logic behind it is if a person orders a taxi before x time then they get charged x else they get charged x (i plan to change it when i manage to get it working), the issue is the price is being added to the car price but not to the function price output. In the function I am trying to only echo a number which isn't meant to be time so am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my particular take:

```
<?php

function rateOffset($now, $cutoff){
    if ($now < strtotime($cutoff)){
        return 20.00;
    } else {
        return 6.00;
    }
}

$cutoff = "18:56";

for ($i = 0; $i < 24; $i++) {
    $now = strtotime("$i:00");
    $rateCalc = rateOffset($now, $cutoff);
    echo date('H:i', $now)." = $rateCalc\n";
}

?>
```

http://ideone.com/owfLg

Note, I'm comparing two arguments, `$now` (which is a timestamp), and `$cutoff`, which is an `hh:mm` representation of the cutoff time to check. The `for` loop is to demonstrate the outcomes per hour, which would be:

```
00:00 = 20
01:00 = 20
02:00 = 20
03:00 = 20
04:00 = 20
05:00 = 20
06:00 = 20
07:00 = 20
08:00 = 20
09:00 = 20
10:00 = 20
11:00 = 20
12:00 = 20
13:00 = 20
14:00 = 20
15:00 = 20
16:00 = 20
17:00 = 20
18:00 = 20
19:00 = 6
20:00 = 6
21:00 = 6
22:00 = 6
23:00 = 6
```

Comment: thanks for the info Jared Farrish, the guy who needs to edit it isn't a php person, so is there anyway we can make it more readable like i did?